# JPA: difference between @JoinColumn and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, identifying-relationship

What's the exact difference between `@JoinColumn` and `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`?

You use `@JoinColumn` for columns that are part of a foreign key. A typical column could look like (e.g. in a join table with additional attributes):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "...")
private OtherClass oc;
```

What happens if I promote the column to be a/the PK, too (a.k.a. identifying relationship)? As the column is now the PK, I must tag it with `@Id`:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "...")
private OtherClass oc;
```

Now the question is:

Are `@Id` + `@JoinColumn` the same as just `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`?:

```
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "...")
private OtherClass oc;
```

If not, what's `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` there for?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> What happens if I promote the column to be a/the PK, too (a.k.a. identifying relationship)? As the column is now the PK, I must tag it with @Id (...).

This enhanced support of **derived identifiers** is actually part of the [new stuff in JPA 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435253/a-concise-clear-list-of-what-is-new-in-jpa2/2440516#2440516) (see the section **2.4.1 Primary Keys Corresponding to Derived Identities** in the JPA 2.0 specification), JPA 1.0 doesn't allow `Id` on a `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne`. With JPA 1.0, you'd have to use `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and also define a `Basic` `Id` mapping for the foreign key column.

> Now the question is: are @Id + @JoinColumn the same as just @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn?

You can obtain a similar result but using an `Id` on `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne` is **much simpler** and is the preferred way to map derived identifiers with JPA 2.0. `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` might still be used in a **JOINED** inheritance strategy. Below the relevant section from the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 11.1.40 PrimaryKeyJoinColumn Annotation
>
> The `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation
>   specifies a primary key column that is
>   used as a foreign key to join to
>   another table.
>
> The `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation
>   is used to join the primary table of
>   an entity subclass in the `JOINED`
>   mapping strategy to the primary table
>   of its superclass; it is used within a
>   `SecondaryTable` annotation to join a
>   secondary table to a primary table;
>   and it may be used in a `OneToOne`
>   mapping in which the primary key of
>   the referencing entity is used as a
>   foreign key to the referenced
>   entity<sup>[108]</sup>.
>
> ...
>
> If no `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`
>   annotation is specified for a subclass
>   in the JOINED mapping strategy, the
>   foreign key columns are assumed to
>   have the same names as the primary key
>   columns of the primary table of the
>   superclass.
>
> ...
>
> **Example:** Customer and ValuedCustomer subclass
>
> ```
> @Entity
> @Table(name="CUST")
> @Inheritance(strategy=JOINED)
> @DiscriminatorValue("CUST")
> public class Customer { ... }
>
> @Entity
> @Table(name="VCUST")
> @DiscriminatorValue("VCUST")
> @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUST_ID")
> public class ValuedCustomer extends Customer { ... }
> ```
>
> <sub>[108] **The derived id mechanisms
>   described in section 2.4.1.1 are now
>   to be preferred over
>   `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` for the
>   OneToOne mapping case.**</sub>

#### See also

- [Primary Keys through OneToOne Relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships)

---

> This source http://weblogs.java.net/blog/felipegaucho/archive/2009/10/24/jpa-join-table-additional-state states that using @ManyToOne and @Id works with JPA 1.x. Who's correct now?

The author is using a pre release **JPA 2.0** compliant version of EclipseLink (version [2.0.0-M7](http://kenai.com/projects/puj/sources/arena/revision/188) at the time of the article) to write an article about JPA 1.0(!). This article is misleading, the author is using something that is **NOT** part of JPA 1.0.

For the record, support of `Id` on `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` has been added in EclipseLink 1.1 (see [this message](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&S=76391a8b637ac8124704d1775fce0fea&th=124643&goto=381663#msg_381663) from [James Sutherland](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User:James.sutherland.oracle.com), EclipseLink comitter and main contributor of the [Java Persistence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) wiki book). But let me insist, this is **NOT** part of JPA 1.0.

Comment: This source

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/felipegaucho/archive/2009/10/24/jpa-join-table-additional-state

states that using @ManyToOne and @Id works with JPA 1.x. Who's correct now?

Comment: OK. Thanks for clearing that up. I am right that the bad example a referred to uses @IdClass wrongly? Shouldn't the @Id annotations be placed at the separate (redundant/duplicate) columns in the entity class to be correct? (ven though I know that using @IdClass is not recommended anymore)

Comment: I mean, there should be two properties in the class: @Id @Column private String institution; and @Id @Column private String competition; just to specify the PK right?

Comment: @Kawu I'm sorry but honestly, it's too hard to discuss this in a small comment box. I'm not even sure I understood what you're talking about. If you have another specific question, I suggest to either pick a JPA implementation and to experiment a bit or to post a *new* question with a full example (and the JPA version). This would make things much easier.

Answer (score 62):

I normally differentiate these two via this diagram:

Use `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`

[image]

Use `JoinColumn`

[image]

Comment: @yusher, `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` use same primary key value to join two tables, and `JoinColumn`, the primary key of main table will become foreign key in another table.

Comment: can you show how you implement it ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but a good time to use `PrimaryKeyColumn` would be if you wanted a unidirectional relationship or had multiple tables all sharing the same id.

In general this is a bad idea and it would be better to use foreign key relationships with `JoinColumn`.

Having said that, if you are working on an older database that used a system like this then that would be a good time to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You use @JoinColumn when you want to manage (change the column name, set nullable and so on) the foreign key column in the target entity table. Here, the Address table will contains User table id like foreign key but the column it's will be name **user_id** (the second scheme of @Sam YC)

```
@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private String id;

private String city;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false)
private User user;
}
```

You use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn, when you want to use the primary key of the referencing entity like the target entity primary key. Here the Address know the referencing User but Address table hasn't foreign key column, because it's has the same `id` than User Id (the first scheme of @Sam YC)

```
@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "foreignKeyGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "foreignKeyGenerator",
        strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                name = "property", value = "userT"
        )
)
private String id;
private String city;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User userT;
}
```