# Hibernate: Can a foreign-cum-primary key be defined as a property rather than a field of a model?

Tags: hibernate

Is it absolutely mandatory for the primary key of a Hibernate model (entity) to be a field rather than a property? I have a table, say 'Purchase', whose primary key, say, cust_id, also acts as a foreign key to a 'Cust' table. Can I define the primary key as a 'Cust' type instead of an int type? What annotations do I need to use? Can someone share a sample code if the above is possible?

Comment: do you want to use **custId** instead of **Cust** in the **Purchase**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the discussion here @ [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417097/jpa-difference-between-joincolumn-and-primarykeyjoincolumn).

In discussion it states you can use `@Id` and `@ManyToOne` on a forign key mapping.

> *Is it absolutely mandatory for the primary key of a Hibernate model (entity) to be a field rather than a property?*

No its not mandatory, for composite primary keys scenario you can have POJOs as primary key have a look at section on composite primary keys in hibernate [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177)