# How to save only subclass related data in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, persistence

I have the following classes

1. Concrete class Item

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "ITEM")
   @Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
   Class Item implements Serializable {        
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Id
     @Column(name = "NAME")
     private final String name;
     @Column(name = "PRICE")
     private BigDecimal price;
   }
   ```
2. Concrete class AddedItem that extends Item

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "ADDED_ITEM")
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "NAME")
   public class AddedItem extends Item {
      @Column(name = "TOTAL_PRICE")
      private BigDecimal totalPrice;
      @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
      private Integer quantity;
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_ID")
      private Invoice invoice;
    }
   ```
3. The Invoice class that has a one to many mapping with AddedItem

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "INVOICE"
   public class Invoice implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "INVOICE_ID")
     private Long billNo;
     @Column(name = "BILLDATE")
     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     private Date billDate;
     @Column(name = "CUSTOMERNAME")
     private String customerName;
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private final List<AddedItem> itemsAdded;
   }
   ```

When I try to save an Invoice instance I am getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ITEM_PK) violated

org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch      update
...
```

How can I tell Hibernate to store only the subclass information as I prefetch the Item related information?

Answer (score 0):

In `@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)` you have to define a `@DiscriminatorColumn` 
to determine the class of the row. Adding this should resolve the problem. If you are using Hibernate 3.1 or lower (hopefully you're not), `@DiscriminatorFormula` should do the job, but I never really tried it personally.

Next on your `AddedItem` entity, the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "NAME")` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417097/jpa-difference-between-joincolumn-and-primarykeyjoincolumn) is pretty much just for show, but it should not cause any harm.

If `AddedItem` is public, so should `Item` entity be.

edit: Since your ID field is a String, are you sure you are using correct unique values for it?