# Why does hibernate want to insert a new entity with the same key if it already exists?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am having the following problem. I have pushed my example into [GitHub](https://github.com/PawelJagus/demo).

If I want to persist an instance of my class `PlayerStatistics` then Hibernate tries to create an already existing entity of `Matchday` (specified as `@ManyToOne`) which I do not want to but I do not seem to get around it.

I am persisting in the `init` method of `DemoApplicationTests`.

```java
@Before
public void init() {
    final Matchday matchday = matchdayRepository.save(new Matchday(1));
    final Club club1 = clubRepository.save(new Club("Klub1"));
    final Club club2 = clubRepository.save(new Club("Klub2"));
    final Match match = matchRepository.save(new Match(matchday, club1, club2));
    final Player player = playerRepository.save(new Player(1, "Jan", "Kowalski", club1)); 
    playerStatisticsRepository.save(new PlayerStatistics(matchday, player, match));
}
```

If I have it like above, then I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [SYS_PK_10114]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.DemoApplicationTests.init(DemoApplicationTests.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2934)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3434)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3170)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2384)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10114 table: MATCHDAY
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10114 table: MATCHDAY
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TransactionManager2PL.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 65 more
```

If I debug the HQL I can clearly see that Hibernate wants to insert a new row into the table `Matchday` even if it already exists.

```sql
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Matchday
        (matchdayNumber) 
    values
        (?)
```

If I comment the last line of the `init()` method then it works OK, so the problem has to be in this part: `playerStatisticsRepository.save(new PlayerStatistics(matchday, player, match))`

```java
@Before
public void init() {
    final Matchday matchday = matchdayRepository.save(new Matchday(1));
    final Club club1 = clubRepository.save(new Club("Klub1"));
    final Club club2 = clubRepository.save(new Club("Klub2"));
    final Match match = matchRepository.save(new Match(matchday, club1, club2));
    final Player player = playerRepository.save(new Player(1, "Jan", "Kowalski", club1)); 
    //playerStatisticsRepository.save(new PlayerStatistics(matchday, player, match));
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

`PlayerStatistics` class looks like that.

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(PlayerStatisticsId.class)
public class PlayerStatistics implements Serializable {
    //...
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Player player;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Matchday matchday;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "matchday_matchdaynumber", referencedColumnName = "matchday_matchdaynumber"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "hometeam_name", referencedColumnName = "hometeam_name") })
    private Match match;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean playedFromTheFirstWhistleblow;

    @Min(0)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int enteredTheFieldAtInSeconds;

    @Min(0)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int leftTheFieldAtInSeconds;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<ScoreType, Integer> statistics = new HashMap<>();

    //...
}
```

## EDIT

If I want to manage it directly from the `Player` entity on the other hand. Then I receive an exception that the entity is already associated with the session, while it does not seem to be.

```java
@Before
public void init() {
    final Matchday matchday = matchdayRepository.save(new Matchday(1));
    final Club club1 = clubRepository.save(new Club("Klub1"));
    final Club club2 = clubRepository.save(new Club("Klub2"));
    final Match match = matchRepository.save(new Match(matchday, club1, club2));
    final Player player = new Player(1, "Jan", "Kowalski", club1);
    player.addPlayerStatistics(new PlayerStatistics(matchday, player, match));
    playerRepository.save(player);
}
```

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.model.Player#1]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.model.Player#1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.DemoApplicationTests.init(DemoApplicationTests.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.model.Player#1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:864)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:850)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:509)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417097/jpa-difference-between-joincolumn-and-primarykeyjoincolumn  seems suggests to me that your choice is either `@Id`+`@JoinColumn`, or `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. However you are now doing  `@Id`+`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.  Cannot help much... the time I was using Hibernate, I can never get `@IdClass` and multiple `@Id` to work (bug of Hibernate at that time I guess) and turned out the easiest way is to always have a surrogate key... :P

Comment: A surrogate key is out of the question. I will try to change the `PrimaryJoinColumn` stuff and see if it works differently.

Comment: @AdrianShum Hmmm, the `ClassId` does seem to be the problem. I will update my question because the problem I am having now is totally different.

Comment: then first make sure you are taking latest hibernate version.  I kind of recall `IdClass` is not working as expected in earlier version

Comment: @AdrianShum Yep, I do have the latest version.

Comment: JPA identity cannot be understand without understanding life cycle, i.e. detached or attached JPA POJO (are known to JPA session or not). Errors in lifecycle can lead to strange exceptions

Comment: @JacekCz It was not about the life cycle after all. However I have to admit that the error message had nothing to do with the real cause of the problem for which I have already posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was in the `PlayerStatisticsId` and the way it was defined.

Originally it looked like this.

```java
public class PlayerStatisticsId implements Serializable {
    //..
    private long player;

    private int matchday;

    public long getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public int getMatchday() {
        return matchday;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof PlayerStatisticsId) {
            final PlayerStatisticsId o = (PlayerStatisticsId) obj;
            return o.matchday == matchday && o.player == player;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I could have sworn that I read somewhere that only the primitives/basic types could be used in a class that is used for `@ClassId`. It does not seem to be the case though.

After changing it to

```java
public class PlayerStatisticsId implements Serializable {
    //...

    private Player player;

    private Matchday matchday;

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public Matchday getMatchday() {
        return matchday;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof PlayerStatisticsId) {
            final PlayerStatisticsId o = (PlayerStatisticsId) obj;
            return o.matchday.equals(matchday) && o.player.equals(player);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It does seem to work. I am receiving a completely different exception now but it is a case for a separate question.